# Pacman collision detection with varying character speeds?

Tags: java, collision-detection, game-engine, collision

I am programming a 2D, grid-based Pacman game. All the tiles are 8x8 in size. In-game, the map tiles are treated as 16x16, and the characters (Pacman and the ghosts) are treated as 32x32. In actuality, they are all pulled from a spritesheet of 8x8 tiles. I store positions as the center point of each character. Since the character tiles are bigger than the map tiles, the map is built in a way that requires the characters being able to "overlap" onto blocked tiles.

To deal with this set of problems, I created an invisible Rectangle and attached it to the character's position. Where the position is an `(x,y)` point, the Rectangle is a box surrounding that point. This rectangle is essentially 16x16 in-game, and is in the center of the character, which allows for the overlap necessary.

This works fine if you're working with 8px as the global movement speed, but I'd like to treat 8px as "100% speed" and have complete control over character speed with a double that is in the range [0,1). The positions are stored as double points, so on that level, this is fine. I read the positions back as integers, though, since I'm working with pixels.

So the question I ask is essentially "if this moves X amount of pixels to direction Y now, will my collision box be touching a blocked tile? But if you're moving 5px at a time, this eventually causes a very obvious issue. Say you're at x = 0, moving right. The tiles are 16x16 in-game, as stated before, and you have two of these open before the third, which is blocked. So you move, x = 5, x = 10, x = 15, x = 20, we just got to the 2nd tile, x = 25, x = 30, x = 35 now we're in the 3rd tile... but wait. We can't go there, because X = 35 collides. And unfortunately, we needed to turn and start moving down, but we can't, because now our Y-axis isn't aligned properly with the grid. Our X position needs to be 32, but can't.

My question for everyone here is, what are my options? What are some ideas or insights you have? I have a feeling I'm making it more difficult than I need to.

Comment: Why not make your move size multiples add up to your total size? That is also multiple of two, for example use speeds of 2, 4 and 8 (maybe 16?).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Thanks for the reply, unfortunately that will not work as the speed would be insanely fast. I could slow the game loop itself down, but then it will be too choppy.

Comment: Then you'll have to scale it. Remember `distance = rate * time`, you appear to know what `time` you want. You appear to know the `distance`. Obviously `rate` must then flow from there.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I don't know why this wasn't obvious to me sooner. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

sounds like you have...

Why not give your "pac-man" sprite a velocity vector? The vector will describe not only the speed at which "pac-man" is traveling but in what direction, meaning you can see ahead.

"pac-man" should be calculating and ultimately making a decision based upon the following conversation..."hey, moving at this speed and in this direction..in so many seconds I'm going to hit a wall, when does that happen?". The seconds don't even have to be seconds...they could be "squares".

You would need a function which takes in the initial movement vector (direction and speed) which returns a coordinate of an X,Y point where "pac-man" must stop, where he cannot go further and must change direction (the center of a tile adjacent to a wall). Each time "pac-man" changes direction, run this calculation again...you do not need to keep checking if the next square is passable. If his direction hasn't changed and his speed is constant..you only need calculate once and let the coordinate system do the rest.

With this approach, square size and velocity is irrelevant...until "pac-man" hits or within his next movement exceeds the stopping point, continue to move along the vector.

Comment: Thanks a lot. As you could probably tell reading my question, I was frustrated as I felt I was just on the verge of the solution. I finally figured it out and have a really slick demo worked out for my class presentation tomorrow.

Comment: Glad to hear it. 

It always helps to suggest improvements to show you really understand the problem. Maybe you could talk about vectors then.